# Objects flashing occasionaly in Flappy Bird pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, flappy-bird-clone

I have coded so far almost the whole Flappy Bird game but the bird, the ground and pipes start "flashing" sometimes. Normally the bird and the ground flash at the same time, when the pipes flash at a different time than the other objects, and sometimes when you have two pipes on the screen, one is flashing but the other is not. I think that it's propably because I have a really old low-end PC, but still, is there any way to solve this issue? The game's code is this:

```
import pygame
import neat
import time
import os
import random

WIN_WIDTH = 500
WIN_HEIGHT = 800


BIRD_IMGS = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs', 'bird1.png'))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs', 'bird2.png'))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs', 'bird3.png')))]
PIPE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs', 'pipe.png')))
BASE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs', 'base.png')))
BG_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('imgs', 'bg.png')))

class Bird:
    IMGS = BIRD_IMGS
    MAX_ROTATION = 25
    ROT_VEL = 20
    ANIMATION_TIME = 5

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tilt = 0
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.vel = 0
        self.height = self.y
        self.img_count = 0
        self.img = self.IMGS[0]

    def jump(self):
        self.vel = -10.5
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.height = self.y

    def move(self):
        self.tick_count += 1

        d = self.vel * self.tick_count + 1.5 * self.tick_count ** 2

        if d >= 16:
            d = 16

        if d < 0:
            d -= 2

        self.y = self.y + d

        if d < 0 or self.y < self.height + 50:
            if self.tilt < self.MAX_ROTATION:
                self.tilt = self.MAX_ROTATION
        else:
            if self.tilt > -90:
                self.tilt -= self.ROT_VEL

    def draw(self, win):
        self.img_count += 1

        if self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*2:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1] 
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*3:
            self.img = self.IMGS[2]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*4:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count == self.ANIMATION_TIME*4 + 1:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
            self.img_count = 0

        if self.tilt <= -80:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
            self.img_count = self.ANIMATION_TIME*2

        rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.img, self.tilt)
        new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center=self.img.get_rect(topleft = (self.x, self.y)).center)
        win.blit(rotated_image, new_rect.topleft)

    def get_mask(self):
        return pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)


class Pipe:
    GAP = 200
    VEL = 5

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.height = 0

        self.top = 0
        self.bottom = 0
        self.PIPE_TOP = pygame.transform.flip(PIPE_IMG, False, True)
        self.PIPE_BOTTOM = PIPE_IMG

        self.passed = False
        self.set_height()

    def set_height(self):
        self.height = random.randrange(50, 450)
        self.top = self.height - self.PIPE_TOP.get_height()
        self.bottom = self.height + self.GAP

    def move(self):
        self.x -= self.VEL

    def draw(self, win):
        win.blit(self.PIPE_TOP, (self.x, self.top))
        win.blit(self.PIPE_BOTTOM, (self.x, self.bottom))

    def collide(self, bird):
        bird_mask = bird.get_mask()
        top_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.PIPE_TOP)
        bottom_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.PIPE_BOTTOM)

        top_offset = (self.x - bird.x, self.top - round(bird.y))
        bottom_offset = (self.x - bird.x, self.bottom - round(bird.y))

        b_point = bird_mask.overlap(bottom_mask, bottom_offset)
        t_point = bird_mask.overlap(top_mask, top_offset)

        if t_point or b_point:
            return True

        return False


class Base:
    VEL = 5
    WIDTH = BASE_IMG.get_width()
    IMG = BASE_IMG

    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y
        self.x1 = 0
        self.x2 = self.WIDTH

    def move(self):
        self.x1 -= self.VEL
        self.x2 -= self.VEL

        if self.x1 + self.WIDTH < 0:
            self.x1 = self.x2 + self.WIDTH

        if self.x2 + self.WIDTH < 0:
            self.x2 = self.x1 + self.WIDTH

    def draw(self, win):
        win.blit(self.IMG, (self.x1, self.y))
        win.blit(self.IMG, (self.x2, self.y))

def draw_window(win, bird, pipes, base):
    win.blit(BG_IMG, (0, 0))

    for pipe in pipes:
        pipe.draw(win)
        pygame.display.update()

    base.draw(win)  

    bird.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()


def main():
    bird = Bird(230, 350)
    base = Base(730)
    pipes = [Pipe(600)]
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    score = 0

    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(30)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        #bird.move()
        add_pipe = False
        rem = []
        for pipe in pipes:
            if pipe.collide(bird):
                pass

            if pipe.x + pipe.PIPE_TOP.get_width() < 0:
                rem.append(pipe)

            if not pipe.passed and pipe.x < bird.x:
                pipe.passed = True
                add_pipe = True

            pipe.move()

        if add_pipe:
            score += 1
            pipes.append(Pipe(600))

        for r in rem:
            pipes.remove(r)

        if bird.y + bird.img.get_height() >= 730:
            pass

        base.move()
        draw_window(win, bird, pipes, base)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because of this

```
for pipe in pipes:
    pipe.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

base.draw(win)  

bird.draw(win)
pygame.display.update()
```

You are updating the screen after your draw each pipe, and then after you draw the bird and base. This will be the problem. you only want to update the screen once per frame. So change it so this

```
for pipe in pipes:
    pipe.draw(win)

base.draw(win)  

bird.draw(win)
pygame.display.update()
```